# how can I make an input field "readonly" using haml?

Tags: ruby, haml

Im a haml newbie

Im trying to figure out how to make an html "input" field for "id", readonly using haml.

the html, should read something like this (not exact reflection)

but the readonly value never comes through

```
%h2 Sections
= semantic_form_for @section do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :id, :readonly => "true"      <-----problem 
    = f.input :title
```

what am I missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
= f.input :id, input_html: { readonly: true }
```